# Signed versus Unsigned Number

Tags: c

In C,
- Signed integer variable can store both nagative and positive numbers
- Unsigned integer variable can store only positive numbers
But, they both will have memory allocated 4 bytes. I read a book and it said if you want to store positive number, we consider using unsigned integer variable so it saves memory. How can it save memory if they both signed and unsigned variables allocate the same size of memory, 4 bytes?

Comment: All numeric types in Java are signed except char. And they're not all 2 bytes long. byte is 1-byte, int is 4-bytes and long is 8-bytes. EIther your book is wrong, or it's not about Java, or you're not reading it correctly. Provide more context.

Comment: Furthermore, a standard integer has FOUR bytes, not two. 2 Bytes is, per definition, a 'short'.

Comment: If your question is about C, why did you tag it with Java???

Answer (score 7):

(This answer is now about C, not Java.)

> How can it save memory if they both signed and unsigned variables allocate the same size of memory, two bytes?

The difference is that, even though they have the same width, the two types can represent different ranges of values. This means that sometimes you have to go to a wider type if you choose signed over unsigned.

For example, let's say you need to represent a value between 0 and 60,000. For this, you have several choices:

- use a 16-bit unsigned integer;
- use a 32-bit signed integer.

As you can see, you have to choose a wider signed type for this range. You can't use a 16-bit signed int because it can only go up to 32,767.

Comment: There is `char` which is an unsigned 16 bit integer.

Comment: @slekcher So do you want answer about `Java` or `C`?

Answer (score 1):

1. There is no unsigned integer type in java(appart from char which is another topic)
2. In the languages where there **are** signed numbers they don't save memory, but rather support for bigger positive values and also provide a way to explicitly state that a given value can not be negative.

Comment: The range's _size_ is the same, it is _placed_ differently. I.e., for chars it is -128 to 127 vs 0 to 255.

Answer (score 1):

To directly answer your question: if you need to store values from 0 to 65535, then you could use one unsigned two-byte value. But if you use signed values, you would be forced to use more bytes, since a two-byte signed value stores only up to 32767. You would have to use, probably a 4-byte signed value, which is of course twice the storage.

Answer (score 1):

You are right that 4 bytes is 4 bytes no matter how it is represented.  The only case where using an unsigned can help in Java is if you have a range of 0 - 65535 and you have a choice of either `char` or `int`.  In this case `char` is smaller.  Note: Storing unsigned numbers in a `char` is usually more confusing than useful however.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you're not going to save memory, since in most cases the size of the integer type you use is much larger than required -- very often you have a value with a range of 0..10 or so in a 32-bit int with a range of +/- 2 billion, when 4 bits would do.

There have been, historically, a few languages & computer systems that "packed" numbers into "odd" bit amounts (and more than a few that used 4-bit decimal digits instead), but no "modern" language (I'm ignoring RPG and COBOL, sorry) does that.

So, once in a blue moon you can save storage using an unsigned value, but it's rare.

It is important to understand the difference between the two types, though, as unsigned values can behave in unexpected ways.  Eg, (and not the strangest case by far) `for( unsigned int i = 100; i < 0; i--)` is an infinite loop, since `i` can never be less than zero.

So with unsigned ints there be dragons.